# Apple association file to app links do not returns a json on a React web project

Tags: ios, reactjs, response, create-react-app, applinks

i have a problem while trying to access this page of my domain:
http://localhost:3000/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

This is where i need to show a JSON response of the apple-app-site-association file, so my iOS application could link with my domain.

So in need to get to link my iOS application to this domain, this address needs to return the file as a JSON response, but instead, it downloads the file.

**
To know:**

- My web project is a CRA React Project.
- The file does need to be without extension.
- I cant use a redirect to a page.
- The test at "https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/" returns "your file's 'content-type' header was not found or was not recognized.".

The app-link android side is OK, while the address has the similar file with ".json" extension, and returns me the response in JSON.